# javascript loop image slideshow

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, loops

```
var imag = document.getElementById('contentimage');
            var imagarr = ["images/contimgtwo.jpg","images/contimg.jpg"]
            //var convertimg = imagarr[i].toString();
            var runtext = function(){
                for (i=0;i<imagarr.length;i++){

                imag.src=imagarr[i];
                }
            }
      setTimeout(runtext,5000);
```

**CSS:**

```
   #contentimage { 
    display:block; 
    top:1600px;
    width:500px; 
    height:400px; 
    position:absolute;
} 

    #contentimage:hover { 
        opacity:0.5; 
        cursor:crosshair;
    }
```

I'm trying to make a image slideshow using a for loop, the idea is that it will provide the .src path with the image path from the array, however the problem is the .src=" " method requires you to " " so I can't call the array and so it doesn't find the image, any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

You should not loop the whole array in your `runtext` function. Doing that you actually apply only the last value of the array and always the last image is shown. Here is a modification of your script which may work:

```
var imag = document.getElementById('contentimage');
var imagarr = ["images/contimgtwo.jpg", "images/contimg.jpg"];
var index = 0, interval;
var runtext = function(){
    imag.src = imagarr[index];
    if(index < imagarr.length-1) {
        index += 1;
    } else {
        index = 0;
    }
    interval = setTimeout(runtext, 5000);
}
var stopText = function() {
    clearTimeout(interval);
}
interval = setTimeout(runtext, 5000);
```

I added a function which stops the slideshow. You still go through all the elements of the array, but the index is incremented on every `runtext` call.

Comment: +1 you approach is the right to solve this problem.  I have found his problem but mine is not a working solution.